# Bound Scipy optimisation of a function returning 1D data

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

this is more of a question on what is an appropriate approach to my problem.

I have a function that takes some 1D vector as input and returns a 1D array (in actuality its a 2D array that is flattened). I am looking to do least squares optimisation of this function. I already have my bounds and constraints on x all sorted, and had thought about doing something like this

```
result = optimize.minimize(func,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=my_bounds,constraints=dict_of_constraints,args=(my_args,))
```

however, this approach uses _minimize_slsqp which requires that the objective function return a scalar. Is there any such approach that would work similarly to the above, but work on an objective function that can return 1D (or 2D?) data?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form a scalar function (a function that returns a single scalar value). Likely something like

```
 ||F(x)||
```

where `||.||` is a norm. This new scalar function can be passed on to `optimize.minimize`.